# How to compare two XML elements from within a xsl:for-loop using XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following problem:

Within a stylesheet document I want to create an output from a relativly simple xml file.
While most of the common XPath and XSLT stuff is not that difficult, comparing two elements and deciding, how to go on is quite a problem right now.

example xml:

```
<root>
    <foo>
        <value>1</value>
        <name>foo1</name>
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <value>2</value>
        <name></name>
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <value>3</value>
        <name>foo3</name>
    </foo>

    <bar>
        <value>1</value>
    </bar>
    <bar>
        <value>2</value>
    </bar>
</root>
```

within the stylesheet is a xsl:for loop, that tries to decide, whether or not the current node shall be displayed:

```
[...]
<xsl:for-each select="bar">
    <xsl:if test="//foo[value=./value]/name">
        <!-- go on, if the content of the 'name' element is not empty -->
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
[...]
```

The intention was only to go on with the stuff, if the content of the 'name' element from 'foo' is not empty, using the euqality of the 'value' element.
The result is, that every line from 'bar' creates an output, event if I intended not to have  one for the second entry, since '//foo[2]/name' is empty.

I'm not sure, how to proceed at the moment... Maybe a generated key would be sufficent!? I don't know...

Thanks for every comment!

Comment: I guess what I'm doing is nothing more than checking '//foo/value' with itself again, and that will most likly always become "true" in the end.

Comment: Hm... In the context, that I maybe using the 'value' node from the 'foo' element to compare it against itselft, I tried to use

    "//foo[value=current()/value]/name"

instead of

    "//foo[value=./value]/name"

and this might do the trick, since the line in question are not longer printed.
But please comment on it, if you have any more suggestions!

Comment: I reached the same conclusion :-) see my answer below.

Comment: Since I use XSLT/XPath only occassionally, my knowledge is unforntunatelly sometimes not adequat to the tasks I want to perform... For example: I understand your aproach, but I would never have thought about the usage of the 'xsl:copy-of' element. Nice one. Will try to remember!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use something like the following:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="//bar">
            <xsl:for-each select="//foo[value=current()/value]">
                <xsl:if test="name != ''">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Most striking is of course that you should use current()/value instead of ./value, because current() refers to the bar element, and . refers to the foo element looped over.

When applied to the input supplied, this gives

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <foo>
        <value>1</value>
        <name>foo1</name>
    </foo>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a key e.g.

```
<xsl:key name="k1" match="foo" use="value"/>
```

as a child of `xsl:stylesheet` and then

```
<xsl:for-each select="bar[normalize-space(key('k1', value)/name)]">...</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: While writng the question, this solution crossed my mind, but because of my unsufficent knowledge my tries were not successful, so I canceled that one and used the simple approach by using '//foo[value=current()/value]/name'.
But thank you anyway - I while try this, too!

Comment: I've just tried it and it works, as you suggested. I was a little bit confused about the XPath query within the 'xsl:for-each', that the result might be the 'foo' node instead of the 'bar', but since the query starts with 'bar', this is nothing more than a misunderstanding :-) Thank you very much!